# How to render parts of an object with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am studying React and I tried to use an API from breaking bad that gives me an object with id, name, img and other things. I can already see the object with console.log but I can't render specific parts of it in my page.

This is how the object appear:

```
0: {char_id: 3, name: "Skyler White", birthday: "08-11-1970", occupation: Array(4), img: "https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/1317262/images/o-ANNA-GUNN-facebook.jpg", …}
```

My code:

```js
    import '../styles/App.css'
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


    export default ({ match }) => {

        useEffect(() => {
            personData();
            console.log(match)
        }, []);

        const [person, setPerson] = useState({});


        const personData = async () => {
            const personData = await fetch(
                `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/${
                match.params.id
                }`
            );

            const person = await personData.json();
            setPerson(person)
            console.log(person)
        }


        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{person.name || "Char name"}</h2>
                <img src={person.img} alt="Char img" />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

[image: Image of my page]

Also, I have this warning in my console:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'match' and 'personData'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Comment: Your console output indicates the json response is an array. To access the properties of that first (only?) element, use `person[0].name` etc. (Or you could change the `setPerson` call to `setPerson(person[0])` instead.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond there is any way to make the number inside [ ] in "setPerson(person[0])" equal to the number I receive from match.params.id ? I tried to use "const arrNum = match.params.id" and then "setPerson(person[arrNum])".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After console logging your code I found, you are getting a response as array of objects. But in view trying to access as object.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({});

  const match = {
    params: {
      id: 1
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    personData();
    console.log(match);
  }, []);

  const personData = async () => {
    const personData = await fetch(
      `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/${match.params.id}`
    );

    const person = await personData.json();
    setPerson(person);
    console.log(person);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{person[0].name || "Char name"}</h2>
      <img
        src={person[0].img}
        alt="Char img"
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
export default ({ match }) => {

    const [person, setPerson] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        personData();
    }, []);


    const personData = async () => {
        const personData = await fetch(
            `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/${
            match.params.id
            }`
        );

        const person = await personData.json();
        setPerson(person)
        console.log(person)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{person[0].name || "Char name"}</h2>
            <img src={person[0].img} alt="Char img" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: There is any way to make the number inside [ ] in "person[0]" equal to the number I receive from match.params.id ? I tried to use "const arrNum = match.params.id" and then "person[arrNum]".

Comment: Yes, you will receive a response in `personData`. Then loop through that array of objects which you will receive as a response and call it this way: `person[index]`

Answer (score -1):

You should pass person variable to useEffect hook. Otherwise it will not update person state.

```
useEffect(() => {
            personData();
            console.log(match)
        }, [person]);
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem and will just uselessly fetch data in a loop (as the effect will run again whenever `person` changes - and the effect itself updates `person`...)

Comment: İf you add an if statement in useEffect and check if person  is empty object then fetch data.